# Tag synonym request: [datediff], [date-diff] and [date-difference]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

The aforementioned tags serve the same purpose across nearly all the languages and their wiki-excerpt mentions the following as well:

> Date-difference will give difference in the number of days, months,
>   years etc. between any two calendar dates. (synonyms in
>   stackoverflow.com: *datediff*, *date-diff*, *date-difference*)

I'd request community to either burninate two of the tags (not voting for it) or synonimize the less used [date-diff](/questions/tagged/date-diff) (13 questions) and [date-difference](/questions/tagged/date-difference) (76 questions) and map it to widely used [datediff](/questions/tagged/datediff) (318 questions).